# Hibernate 4.0 hibernatetool taskdef error

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl

I'm using hibernate 4.0.0.CR4 and was trying the "Message" example from Java Persistence with Hibernate. I was able to compile and run the applicaiton using the ant build, but when i try exporting schema using hibernatetool i'm getting an error

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project name="HelloWorld" default="compile"  basedir=".">
    <property name="proj.name" value="HelloWorld"/>
    <property name="proj.version" value="1.0"/>

    <!-- Global properties for this build  -->
    <property name="src.java.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="bin"/>

    <path id="project.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            <include name="**/*.zip"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Useful shortcuts -->
    <patternset id="meta.files">
        <include name="**/*.xml"/>
        <include name="**/*.properties"/>
    </patternset>

    <!-- Cleanup -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Compile Java source -->
    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac
            srcdir="${src.java.dir}"
            destdir="${build.dir}"
            nowarn="on">
            <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- Copy metadata to build classpath -->
    <target name="copymetafiles">
        <copy todir="${build.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.java.dir}">
                <patternset refid="meta.files"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!--Run HelloWorld -->
    <target name="run" depends="compile, copymetafiles"
        description="Build and run HelloWorld">
        <java fork="true"
            classname="hello.HelloWorld"
            classpathref="project.classpath">
            <classpath path="${build.dir}"/>
        </java>
    </target>
    <!-- SchemaExporter -->
    <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask"
        classpathref="project.classpath"/>
    <target name="schemaexport" depends="compile, copymetafiles"
        description="Exports a generated schema to DB and files">
        <hibernatetool destdir="${basedir}">
            <classpath path="${build.dir}"/>
            <configuration configurationfile="${build.dir}/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
            <hbm2ddl
                drop="true"
                create="true"
                export="true"
                outputfilename="helloworld-ddl.sql"
                delimiter=";"
                format="true"/>
        </hibernatetool>
    </target>
</project>
```

error:

```
/home/student/workspace/HelloWorld/build.xml:61: taskdef A class needed by class org.hibernate.tool.ant.EnversHibernateToolTask cannot be found: org/hibernate/tool/ant/HibernateToolTask
```

following are the jars on my class path:
    antlr-2.7.7.jar
    classmate-0.5.4.jar
    commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
    commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
    dom4j-1.6.1.jar
    hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.0.CR2.jar
    hibernate-core-4.0.0.CR4.jar
    hibernate-envers-4.0.0.CR4.jar
    hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
    hsqldb.jar
    jandex-1.0.3.Final.jar
    javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
    jboss-logging-3.0.0.GA.jar
    jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar

On few forums I found that the missing class is part of hibernate-tools.jar but I couldn't find this jar in the version of hibernate (http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/4.0.0.CR4/)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the node  inside of

```
<target name="schemaexport" depends="compile, copymetafiles"
    description="Exports a generated schema to DB and files">
    <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask"
        classpathref="project.classpath"/>

    <hibernatetool destdir="${basedir}">
        <classpath path="${build.dir}"/>
        <configuration configurationfile="${build.dir}/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <hbm2ddl
            drop="true"
            create="true"
            export="true"
            outputfilename="helloworld-ddl.sql"
            delimiter=";"
            format="true"/>
    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```